# Regalar expression - How to escape

Tags: regex, escaping

I can't understand how to escape in regular expression.
I know that if I put a '\' before a character it should match that char literally.

But if I type

```
echo "hello 8 9 2013" | grep -e "^hello|hello$"
```

I get nothing.
While if I type

```
echo "ciao 8 9 2013" | grep -e "^ciao\|ciao$"
```

it works properly.

Someone can explain me the reason of this behavior?

In the second code I would expect grep to look for a "|", while in the first one I would expect grep to interpret it as an "or". But I get exactly the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `grep` implements "basic" regular expressions, in which `|` is a normal character, while `\|` is the alternation operator. If you use `grep -E` (or the older name `egrep`), it implements "extended" regular expressions, which works the opposite way for this operator.

The difference between basic and extended regular expressions is explained here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html

Comment: Thank you, it all make sense now. Do you have a list of the others "normal character"?

Comment: I added a link to a page that describes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Default regex engine in `grep` is **basic regular expressions (BREs)** and that requires `|` to be escaped.

You can override this behavior by using `-E` **extended regular expressions** like this:

```
echo "hello 8 9 2013" | grep -E "^hello|hello$"
```

As per `man grep`:

```
-E, --extended-regexp
  Interpret pattern as an extended regular expression (i.e. force grep to behave as egrep).
```

Comment: FYI: *[POSIX BRE does not support any other features. Even alternation is not supported.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)*